# Quake 3 Cheats - Enable Give All Persistently

Tags: cheats, quake-3

I have disabled pure server to try out some of the built-in cheats.  I like using '/give all' but as soon as you die you lose all weapons.  Is there a way to persist this throughout an entire map, even after respawning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could bind it to a key (ie, in your client's config file, /bind keyname give all) and press the key every respawn, but that might get tedious.

If you want the server to do this for you, you're going to need a server-side mod, I believe.  The stock game doesn't support things such as this.

I think you're going for a CTF server, but Rocket Arena (or more specifically, the Clan Arena mode) is pretty much what you're describing.  [Rocket Arena 3](http://www.ausgamers.com/files/details/html/14264) for Quake 3 is one good mod for this.

Another option would be to try and tweak [OSP Tourney mod](http://www.orangesmoothie.org/tourneyQ3A/) (download link there is busted, [try here instead](http://www.quakeunity.com/file=1407)) to do something similar.  They have a Rocket Arena-style mode, and it's likely that there are options for spawning players with non-default loadouts.

Beryllium also looks promising, you can generate a config file online and download the mod from [this site.](http://planetreload.com/configgen/beryllium/)

There may be other mods out there that are easier to use and come with more features that you'd like, but you're going to have to [do some searching](http://www.quakeunity.com/downloads/8) to find which one works the best for your situation.

Comment: Thanks...I did the key binding for now.  Will look into my own mod for this sometime soon (probably more questions!)